# ServiceStack PocoDynamo C# Query on Nested object property

Tags: servicestack, pocodynamo

Below is my dynamodb row object structure.
Status, Calls are 1st level columns and Inside Calls, i have nested data.

```
Record
      ->Status : 0
      ->Calls
             -[0]:CapIndex : 5
             -[1]:CapIndex : 0
```

What is the scan query in Servicestack and I need to fetch rows with Status=0 and if any of the Calls having CapIndex=0

I tried the below but it was throwing  exception

```
dynamoClient.FromScan<Cache>(x=>x.Status==0 && x.Calls.Any(y=>y.CapIndex == 0)).Exec()
```

Exception:
variable 'x' of type 'Cache' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Any idea folks?

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform a server side query on a nested complex type, you would need to perform the nested complex type query on the client after executing the Dynamo DB Query, e.g:

```
var results = dynamoClient.FromScan<Cache>(x=>x.Status==0).Exec()
  .Where(x => x.Calls.Any(y=>y.CapIndex == 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: But mythz, 
In that case, I will always hit Dynamo irrespective of whether there are records which match my filter or not, and there is cost involved with every hit.

Comment: @DileepNamburu How were you expecting to make a Dynamo query without hitting it? Either way as per my answer PocoDynamo doesn't support server queries on nested objects, if you want you can access AWS's underlying `IAamazonDynamoDb` client with `dynamoClient.DynamoDb` otherwise if you want to avoid the client side filter you'll need to look at splitting out the nested type into a first class table.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Can you please explain about "to access AWS's underlying IAamazonDynamoDb client with dynamoClient.DynamoDb" ?